# AMPL If-Then statements for Linear Programming

Tags: if-statement, linear-programming, ampl

This is the context:

I'm making 3 chairs:  A, B, C
I have 5 materials: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

The table looks like this:

```
              A (kg)      B (kg)      C (kg)      Supply (kg)
1             3           3.75        2.75        750
2             1           1.25        1.75        425
3             0.75        0.5         0.875       300
4             0.75        1.5         1.375       424
5             0.625       0.75        0.75        199
```

The question is:
I have to use material 1 in all chairs.
I have a choice between using:       material 2 and 4          &           material 3 and 5.
I have to use only one of them. Not both.

For example: The possible combinations of materials are:

1,2,3 or 1,2,5 or 1,3,4 or 1,4,5

Our objective is to maximize profit.

I've done all the modelling on the .dat and .mod files for the context of this question. I need help with the constraints and variables on the .mod file. i.e. 'Subject to'

How do I code this on to AMPL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make additional variable x:

`var x{i in material, j in chair} binary;` 
this variable to decide which material used in every chair.

then put additional constraint:

`subject to constraint1{j in chair}: x[2,j]+x[4,j]=1;`

`subject to constraint2{j in chair}: x[3,j]+x[5,j]=1;`